# how compiler infers the type in java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have generic method which looks something like this.

```
public static <T> T addAndReturn(T element, Collection<T> collection){
    collection.add(element);
    return element;
}
```

When I call

```
String stringElement = "stringElement";
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object theElement = addAndReturn(stringElement, objectList);
```

It infers the type as object.

When I call

```
Object objectElement = new Object();
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
Object theElement = addAndReturn(objectElement, stringList);
```

the compiler reports error.

What are the rules behind this?

Comment: A full explanation of "the rules behind [generics]" is rather broad for SO ... Suggest you check out the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for an overview, or [Angelika Langer's excellent FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more in-depth coverage.

Comment: Also see [*"Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/2891664) We can turn a `String` in to an `Object` but we can't turn a `List<String>` in to a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are passing a `List<Object>` to the `Collection<T>` so `T` must be an `Object` type.  A `String stringElement` is a sub-class of `Object` so this is allowed.

In the second case, you are passing a `List<String>` to the `Collection<T>` so `T` can only be `String`. As `Object objectElement` is not a `String` type this is not allowed.

You can't add an `Object` to a `List<String>` which seems reasonable.

Comment: that helps.So the last parameter in the function will always have higher preference?

Comment: @starkk92 the most restrictive parameter will dominate.

Answer (score 1):

Generics can be difficult to grasp, I recommend you read up on it carefully.

In your example, you have a type `T` which can be any one type. This type is "generic" in that it conforms to what type is put into it. So, when you pass an `ArrayList<String>` as the `Collection<T>` parameter, `T` becomes `String` in that instance. Therefore, the return type of the method becomes `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Generics work on principle of Type inference. The compiler checks the type which from the generic class. Once the type is determined the compiler performs compile time type checking to make sure that all the type which are passed are correct. Generics also has type erasure at runtime but that is a different thing and we can skip it for this discussion.

To apply this principle on your questions:
In the first case you are creating an object of type String which can be easily added to a ArrayList of type Object as String is a sub class of Object.

For the second example you are now doing the exact opposite. You are trying to save a Object class object in a reference of String class which is not allowed.

Thus if you notice the rules are exactly same even as that of a non generic code.